# Signalr server method is not calling using objHub.server

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr-hub

I am already googled about this but not found any solution.

My hub's methods are like this

```
public string Test(string hello)
{
    return hello;
}
public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
{
    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

and my client side is

```
var objHub = $.connection.myHub;
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    objHub.server.test('test');
}).fail(function () {
    /.....
})
```

`OnConnected` is calling perfectly but `objHub.server.test` is not calling.

Even I have checked in console for server side methods mapping to hub object and here is all server methods are registered with hub object

[image]

Why my server side methods are not calling?

**Update**

Now what I am seeing

Server is requesting to

`http://localhost:83/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=MUM0NzA5MDI3QTEyRjM5RDM4QjEzNDhGRTFEMjJGNzI3QTcyQTRDM0ZDOTE3MTRCRUYwQkVCOUI3OEQ3Q0MxREY1NzNEQkUzQjAxM0QzMzlCRDIzQUY0OUJDNThENDVCMDUzQ0RENEMwQTUzNkNFMzEyNDY2QTkyMjExRkE4REVDMUZGRUE2RTdFNTNDRkM2NDg5NjEzMUIyMzQzNDI4Njk3RjRBNTdEMDlEQ0U1MUJGQ0I4RjE4Njg3NjU5NTBFRURGQTZCNzBGMzUwRjA0MzdFOERENkQ1NTFEQ0JCNEJDN0U3NDUyNA%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%5D`

And getting this error

**`Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task 1<Microsoft.Owin.IFormCollection> Microsoft.Owin.OwinRequest.ReadFormAsync()`**

Thanks

Comment: Try to add a timeout like `setTimeout(function () { $.connection.hub.start().done... }, 5000);`

Comment: already tried it

Comment: Does the execution go into the event fail?

Comment: Now I am seeing this error while signalr connect request `Method not found: System.Threading.Tasks.Task1<Microsoft.Owin.IFormCollection> Microsoft.Owin.OwinRequest.ReadFormAsync()`

Comment: Did you update the packages? Apparently you are using a version that does not contain this method. Is `Microsoft.Owin` in the project references? If yes, try to remove and add again.

Comment: Thanks @PiLHA I have version issue of `Microsoft.Owin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I updated my Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR2.2.2 when I revert to Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR2.2.0 then it working........